# How can you change the color of an iframe border?

Tags: html, css

I have a quiz for school in which I have an iframe that plays a YouTube video. My question is about the possibility of changing the iframe's border color.

Comment: Post your relevant html and css. How did you add your border?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, if you want quick and accurate help with your code you must include it on the question ... How are you creating that border you already have ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the CSS `border` property. You can read more about the options here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

```css
iframe {
  border: 1em solid red;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QuMGc0EswTc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the following CSS:

```css
iframe {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

You can change the styles as needed. Good luck!